# How to check if set of 50-d vectors comes from the multivariable normal distribution in Python?

Tags: normal-distribution, python, multivariate-normal-distribution, multivariate-distribution

I have a data set that consists of 18000 rows and 50 columns. Each row represents an observation and each observation is a vector with 50 components.

Is there any way in Python for me to check if these observations originate from a multivariable normal distribution ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/392037/using-r-q-statistic-to-check-multivariate-normality/392053#392053 for a list of such tests and some discussion.

Comment: Ok thanks, will do. :)